# How to make updateprogess control trigger on 1 view inside multiview

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, multiview, updateprogress

I have a multiview control with 6 panels.

The multiview is encased within an update panel.

When panel 6 is active, a webservice is called that can take up to a minute. I want to show a progress panel - block the ui , present a centralised panel informing the user what is happening.

I have placed am updateprogress control on the page outside the update panel, however this would trigger for all panels if there was a delay.

How can I make the update progress control appear just when the 6th panel is being rendered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue after testing a few variations.

I put the updateprogress control inside view 6 and it seems to kick in when only that view is shown.